# Get all pdf and doc files from svn repository

Tags: c#, svn

How can I get all pdf and doc file from svn path?

I tried:

```
arguments = $"list -R {link} | grep .pdf ";
  

arguments = $"list -R {link} | find.pdf ";
```

but it returns nothing.

```
arguments = $"list -R {link} "
```

it return all files and there is pdf and doc files.

This works in cmd:
svn.exe list -R http://_________ | find ".pdf"

Comment: Have you tried `$"list -R {link} | find \".pdf\"";`

Comment: yes :/ Still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
arguments = $"list -R {link}{s} --search .pdf";
```